# How to set up a heartbeat function for Discord gateway

Tags: javascript, websocket, discord

This is not going to be a very specific question on solving one issue, so apologies for that. This is sort of a follow-up to a previous question I asked about getting a live server count for my Discord bot's website. It seems to me like a websocket connection is the best way to get this information, as getting this info through discord.js took way too much memory because discord.js does much more than what I need.

I know that for a websocket connection, I need to get a connection URL, connect, and then heartbeat and receive heartbeat acknowledges. I'm having a ton of trouble actually getting these ideas into code though. So far I can request a URL, connect, and start heartbeating, but I have no idea how to 1) keep heartbeating while also receiving information and 2) stop heartbeating if the connection is interrupted (I don't receive an acknowledge). The main thing causing me issues is the inability to work with multiple message listeners. If anyone could point me in the right general direction to go or the fix for my current issues, it would be greatly appreciated.

Current code, if it helps (I know it doesn't really work):

```js
const XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest
const WebSocket = require('ws')

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onload = (req, res) => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
        main(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))
    } else {
        console.error(`ReadyState: ${xhr.readyState}    Status: ${xhr.status}`)
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", 'https://discord.com/api/gateway/bot', false)
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "MY_BOT_TOKEN_THIS_IS_A_PLACEHOLDER_DONT_TELL_ME_ITS_WRONG_IN_COMMENTS")
xhr.send()

function main(response) {
    let socket = new WebSocket(`${response.url}/?v=6&encoding=json`)
    var hello
    socket.onopen = (event) => {
        console.log("Connection established")
    }
    socket.onclose = (event) => {
        console.log(`Connection closed: code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`)
    }
    socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        console.log(`Data received: ${event.data}`)
        hello = JSON.parse(event.data)
        if (hello.op == 10) {
            let alive = true
            heartbeat(socket, hello.s, hello.d.heartbeat_interval, alive)
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                "op": 2,
                "d": {
                    "token": "MY_BOT_TOKEN_THIS_IS_A_PLACEHOLDER_DONT_TELL_ME_ITS_WRONG_IN_COMMENTS",
                    "properties": {
                        "$os": "windows",
                        "$device": "test",
                        "$browser": "test"
                    },
                    "guild_subscriptions": false,
                    "intents": 1
                }
            }))
            socket.removeEventListener('message')
            socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
                if (JSON.parse(event.data).op !== 11) {
                    console.log(`Message received: ${event.data}`)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}

function heartbeat(socket, s, interval, alive) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({"op": 1, "d": s}))
    console.log("Heartbeat sent")
    setTimeout(() => {
        alive = false
    }, interval)
}

function listenForMessage(event) {
    if (JSON.parse(event.data).op === 11) {
        let data = JSON.parse(event.data)
        console.log(`Heartbeat received: ${event.data}`)
        if (data.hasOwnProperty("s")) {
            s = data.s
        }
        socket.removeEventListener('message')
        if (alive) {
            heartbeat(socket, s, interval)
            socket.addEventListener('message', listenForMessage)
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few tips.

1. `let alert` is in the wrong place. It should be scoped right under `let WebSocket`.
2. Don't `removeEventListener`. Much better to have one message handler, `switch (message.op)`, and then call out to other methods based on the value of `message.op` (what you have named `hello`).
3. If you really want to `removeEventListener`, you can't only pass the type `"message"`, you need to also pass a reference to the function itself. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) and below.
4. If you need to save that first message, the value of `hello`, then also scope that at the top level of the file.
5. You don't say what you want to do when you stop heartbeating, but you have the location for it already, it's where you set `alive = false`. You could call `socket.close()` there or `alert` your user something's gone wrong. Depends on your app.

```js
const myHandler = function (data) { /* do stuff with data */ };
socket.addEventListener("message", myHandler);
socket.removeEventListener("message", myHandler);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use a different code because I couldn't find another one and I have a problem when I try to send 3 heartbeat the connection is disconnected
Connection closed: code = 1000 reason =

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30637628)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).